# How to restrict a lotus view to the content of some folders?

Tags: view, designer, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I am trying to make a view which selects all unread mails which also belong to a specific list of folders and subfolders.

I created a view by coying the existing "view unread" one, but despite my research in the documentation and in google I am at a loss as to how to restrict the content of the view to documents in a list of folders. 
The list of folder can be hard coded, even better would be to only have to provide top folders name.

folder structure is like this : 
mailer-daemon
alerts
 app1
  prod
  rec
  dev
 app2
  prod
  rec
  dev

I want the view to restrict to app1/prod and app2/prod. this is in lotus notes 6.5.4 CCH6

The unread formula looks like this (and works ok):

```
SELECT @IsNotMember("A"; ExcludeFromView) & IsMailStationery != 1 & Form != "Group" & Form != "Person"
```

how to restrict it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Folder membership isn't a property in the document, and since you cannot do a @dblookup in the SELECT formula you cannot check during view build if the documents are present in the folders.

If you have control over the process when documents are sorted into the folders, you could stamp some value to the documents and use it for selection - or add the document to a "global" folder and use that instead of the view.

Comment: My opinion of lotus lowers again   :(